# how to exclude 1 column from composite key while generating table

Tags: spring-boot

composite  key contains 2 columns, when i am giving @ManyToOne, it is adding 2 columns (employee_dept_id, employee_emp_id) in child table, but i want to  exlclude employee_dept_id column while generating table

Employee.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "emp_tbl")
@IdClass(EmployeePKId.class)
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int empId;
    
    @Id
    private int deptId;
    
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Laptop> laptops;
}


 Laptop.java

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "laptop_tbl")
@IdClass(LaptopPKId.class)
public class Laptop {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int laptopId;
    
    @Id
    private int laptopModel;
    
    private String laptopBrand;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    private Employee employee;
}

 ChargingRuleApplication.java

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ChargingRuleApplication {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(ChargingRuleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public Employee save(@RequestBody Employee employee) {

employee.getLaptops().forEach(laptop -> {
laptop.setEmployee(employee);
        });

Employee emp = repository.save(employee);

return emp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you not look at all what you posted? Why would you put "1. " in front of every line. Please don't do things like that.